# Dropdown selection in url?

Tags: web-scraping, web, kimono

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this but I figured I would give it a try. I'm trying to scrape some data off of this website: https://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/full-fantasy-basketball-projections using Kimono Labs. However, I want to be able to scrape it from "DraftKings" instead of "FanDuel". Is there a way I can somehow in the URL make this selection so it knows to go straight into draftkings when it goes into this page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible right now. See the [review post](http://scraping.pro/kimono-labs-review/) of the Kimono API.